# How to connect website to windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, logic, freeze

I have one **web application** and one **windows application**

What i want to do is 
There are two tables which are same in web and windows both application
I have one **export button** in my website
Where all the **insert queries** are generated which later will be inserted to my windows application and then i just have to paste that queries to my windows application and execute it

All seems to be working my question is :-

1. Is this **right idea to do?**
2. Both database have one **datatype image** so in that case query **hangs up** and when query generated its about **600pages** which obviously killing my sql server what to do now

Comment: Try MultiThreading ... that might help split the objects and do the process

Comment: @aravind i don't get you

Comment: Stooped question probably, but Why don't you just connect your app to the same DB that the website uses? Is the DB too big to access remotely?

Comment: Ya i have to do manually because my client needs some of records only and to do it manually so first queries will be created and then he will insert it just copy paste it into a server

Comment: Why dont you just connect your app to teh remote db (website db), get the records you need, put them in the app's local db... and its done?

Comment: Can you explain me how i don't have any idea about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your local app:

- Make a connection to your remote DB
- Look for the records you want  in this remote db
- Step through them, and add those records to your local app's db

Connect to remote db:
https://www.google.co.za/search?q=c%23+conenct+to+remote+db&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=GQaPUuelAoejhgf6u4CAAQ#channel=fflb&q=c%23+connect+to+remote+db&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1

Comment: Gud one gives me idea and certainly i can do by this one

Comment: Great. Sure you'll get it in the bag. Cheers.